# Draw on canvas using bitmap pixels?

Tags: android, bitmap, android-canvas

I have an app that allows the user to draw grids of circles, rectangles, arrows, and paint. All of these are drawn on bitmaps which are in turn drawn on my main canvas. I have it structured this way because the users can zoom/pan on the main canvas (via a main bitmap) as well as move/scale/rotate each drawn object.  The problem is that all these bitmaps eat up all of my memory, so I have been trying to find a better solution.

LRUcache is out of the question because I need all of the bitmaps every time the onDraw method is called, which is every time something new is drawn.

I have seen the Bitmap.getPixels() function and the Canvas.drawPoints(); function. Is there a way to use these together so I can get rid of my bitmaps? What I envision is creating a bitmap, drawing the object on it, extracting the pixels from that bitmap, and then recycling the bitmap to free up that memory. Is that feasible?

Comment: I am indeed facing the same issue, but I have just Canvas alone by which I am drawing a tree like structure without using bitmap. Anyways, did you try by saving your canvas state ?